# How to fetch data and display it in grandchild component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props, react-component

I have a parent component and here I fetch data:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BoxWithSearch from "../components/sub-components/BoxWithSearch";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listCompanies } from "../actions/companyActions";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const companyList = useSelector((state) => state.companyList);
  const { companies } = companyList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listCompanies());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h3 className="title">Brands</h3>
              <BoxWithSearch type={"companies"} companies={companies} 
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So companies are coming like this:
[

```
  {
    "slug": "Dickens-Franecki",
    "name": "Dickens - Franecki",
    "address": "12158 Randall Port",
    "city": "East Maureenbury",
    "state": "NE",
    "zip": "74529",
    "account": 31010023,
    "contact": "Lonzo Stracke"
  },
  {
    "slug": "Weissnat-Schowalter-and-Koelpin",
    "name": "Weissnat, Schowalter and Koelpin",
    "address": "92027 Murphy Cove",
    "city": "Port Malachi",
    "state": "WY",
    "zip": "56670-0684",
    "account": 81813543,
    "contact": "Kathryne Ernser"
  },
]
```

I am trying to display these companies as a checkbox but HomeScreen' child component is BoxWithSearch component:

```
import React from "react";
import CheckBox from "../custom-components/CheckBox";

export default function BoxWithSearch(props) {
  return (
    <div className="search-w-box card">
      <div className="card-header">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder={`Search ${props.type}`}
          aria-label="Recipient's username"
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        {this.props && this.props.map((prop) => <CheckBox text={prop.name} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And later it goes to the checkbox:

```
import React from "react";

export default function CheckBox(props) {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleCheck = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked || !isChecked);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <label className="checkbox-container">
        {props.text}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={(e) => toggleCheck(e)}
          id={props.id}
        />
        <span className="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

But unfortunately, I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props') and I am really confused and dont know what to do about it.

Could you please have a look?
Thanks...

Comment: Based on your code you're passing an object to `BoxWithSearch` (a single company), so there's nothing you can map on, it's not an array. And you're passing a single string to `CheckBox`, a company name as `text`, so you won't find something like `props.id`

Comment: I edited the code and now I am sending like this: <BoxWithSearch type={"Brands"} companies={companies} /> but still I am getting ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're passing props like this: `<BoxWithSearch type={"companies"} companies={companies} />`, you should expect to have in your `BoxWithSearch` component a `props` object with properties `type` and `companies`. So in `BoxWithSearch` you can map through the companies property like this:

```
props.companies.map((prop) => <CheckBox text={prop.name} />
```

Note that here you're just passing a `text` property to `CheckBox` but in your code you're also looking for `id`. So I guess you should have something like this:

```
props.companies.map((prop) => <CheckBox text={prop.name} id={prop.id} />
```